# Are there tools to convert existing DNS configuration to Amazon Route 53?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'd like to convert all my domain names/DNS configuration to use Amazon Route 53.

I'm wondering if there are any tools available that take existing DNS records and convert them for use with Amazon Route 53.

Comment: slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862542/amazon-aws-route-53-gui-tools

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides BIND 2 Route53 conversion tool here: http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/9489892636320520.

Haven't used it though.